What are alternatives for langchain on Python?
What are alternatives for langchain on Python? A library being an abstraction to interact with other libraries such as OpenAI's.

https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack is a pretty popular alternative to Langchain. Apache 2.0 and almost 20k GitHub stars.
